# Firebase Cloud Functions via Typescript - index.js does not exists

Tags: typescript, firebase, function, google-cloud-functions, package.json

I have created a repo with angular/fire and cloud functions.
No i want to run the functions emulator, but it tells me, that index.js doesn't exist.
But how should it exists, when i use Typescript?
In functions/src/ i have a index.ts and it should us this instead.
But when i set "main":"src/index.ts" in package.json i got this error:

Failed to load functions definition from source: FirebaseError: Failed to load functions definition from source: Failed to generate manifest from functions source: SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

> But when i set "main":"src/index.ts" in package.json

Bad idea. Typescript is a compile time language, it cannot be executed as it is. It needs to be converted Javascript first.

Did you build the package with `npm run build` before starting the emulator? It will create the index.js for you.

I think they added it to the documentation now: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript?gen=2nd#using_an_existing_typescript_project

Comment: And how can i solve this?

Comment: Run `npm run build` ? Updating the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to run the `npm run build` command to generate the index.js file. Which will be located in the functions/lib/ folder.

The error message is clear, that you are using the import statement in the wrong place.

Where as the correct import is:

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
admin.initializeApp();
```

Comment: Can you point at the link in the documentation that says to execute `npm run build`?